# How to beat a JavaScript condition riddle?

Tags: javascript

I am using a foreach loop in php to load data from a mysql table. I'm using the data ID's loaded from the data base and applying it to the button values.

The buttons come in two colors, green and white. The buttons represent likes for liking comments or posts.

The total existing number of likes starts at 6 (div id="total")

**white buttons**

If button 1 has color of white and you click it, total likes (6) will increase by 1. If you click button 1 again, total likes (7) will decrease by 1.

If button 1, button 2, and button three are clicked, total likes (6) increases by 3 ( 1 for each button). If button 1, button 2 and button 3 are clicked again, the total likes (9) will decrease by 3.

**The Puzzle**

**Green buttons**

How do I make it so, When a green button is clicked, the total (6)  decrease by 1, and if the button is clicked again, it should increase by 1. Unlike white buttons.

If Green button 3, 5 and 6 are clicked, the total (6) should decease by 3. if the same buttons are clicked again, total (6) increases by 3.

**Here is my code**

```js
var colorcode = "rgb(116, 204, 49)";
var buttonid = str;
var elem = document.getElementById(buttonid);
var theCSSprop = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("background-color");

var initialtotal = parseInt(document.getElementById("total").innerHTML, 10);
var likes = new Array();

function showUser(str) {
  ////// 1st condition /////
  if (theCSSprop == colorcode) {

    if (likes[value] == 0 || !likes[value]) {
      likes[value] = 1;
    } else {
      likes[value] = 0;
    }
    var sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < likes.length; i++) {
      if (likes[i] == 1) {
        sum--
      }
    }

  }
  ////// 2nd condition /////
  else {
    if (likes[str] == 0 || !likes[str]) {
      likes[str] = 1;
    } else {
      likes[str] = 0;
    }

    var sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < likes.length; i++) {
      if (likes[i] == 1) {
        sum++
      }
    }

  }
  var tot = initialtotal + sum;

  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = tot;

}
```

```html
<div id="total" style="width:100px;padding:50px 0px; background-color:whitesmoke;text-align:center;">6 </div>

<!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<button id="5" value="5" onclick="showUser(this.value)">LIKE </button>

<button id="346" value="346" onclick="showUser(this.value)" style="background-color:rgb(116, 204, 49);">LIKE </button>

<button id="128" value="128" onclick="showUser(this.value)" style="background-color:rgb(116, 204, 49);">LIKE </button>

<button id="687" value="687" onclick="showUser(this.value)">LIKE </button>

<button id="183" value="183" onclick="showUser(this.value)" style="background-color:rgb(116, 204, 49);">LIKE </button>

<button id="555" value="555" onclick="showUser(this.value)">LIKE </button>
<!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
```

Comment: I don't see a question anywhere in here.

Comment: I see all your buttons share the same `id`... ID's should be unique!

Comment: @Barma I've edited the post and asked a question. I am trying to make green buttons decrease the total values.

Comment: Ops sorry the button ids are the same as the vlues of the button, Ill change that now

Comment: Where do you set `str` before you do `var buttonid = str;`?

Comment: str is set every time a button is clicked using it value and id. I've also used the str value to define arrays

Comment: For a green button to change direction, does it have to be the same green button, or any green button?

Comment: That `str` is local to the `showUser()` function. I'm talking about the global variable `str` that you use to initialize `buttonid` outside the function.

Comment: Hmm, maybe i should use the str inside the function since its changing everytime the function is called

Comment: any and all green button with rgb(116, 204, 49)

Comment: I visualised it like this, storing arrays with key and values for each time a button is clicked.  var likes [ 0, 1 , 1  , 0 , -1 ]

Comment: @Barmar I really appreciate any help

Comment: I'm working on an answer. But what is `value` in `likes[value]`? You've never declared that variable anywhere.

Comment: What does PHP have to do with this question? The fact that the buttons were created in PHP is totally irrelevant to the Javascript -- it doesn't care where the values came from.

Comment: you're right. value is not relevant. ''Str'' should is in there instead of ''value''

Comment: php was mentioned as I just wanted to mention that the buttons are dynamic and they are fetched from a db, to avoid answers that may be applicable for only 6 buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing `this.value` to `showUser()`, just pass `this`. That way, the function can get the value and the style directly, without having to call `getElementById()` (you're not passing the ID). Then you need to set `theCSSprop` inside the function, so it's the property of the current button.

To make green buttons alternate direction from increment to decrement, you need a global variable that remembers what it did the last time the function was called.

Also, you don't need to write `if(likes[str] == 0 || !likes[str])`, since `0` is faley. Just write `if(!likes[str])`.

```js
var colorcode = "rgb(116, 204, 49)";

var likes = new Array();
var greenIncr = -1;

function showUser(elem) {
  var initialtotal = parseInt(document.getElementById("total").innerHTML, 10);
  ////// 1st condition /////
  var str = elem.value;
  var theCSSprop = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("background-color");
  if (theCSSprop == colorcode) {

    if (!likes[str]) {
      likes[str] = 1;
    } else {
      likes[str] = 0;
    }
    var sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < likes.length; i++) {
      if (likes[i] == 1) {
        sum += greenIncr;
      }
    }
    greenIncr = -greenIncr; // revese the direction of green button

  }
  ////// 2nd condition /////
  else {
    if (!likes[str]) {
      likes[str] = 1;
    } else {
      likes[str] = 0;
    }

    var sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < likes.length; i++) {
      if (likes[i] == 1) {
        sum++
      }
    }

  }
  var tot = initialtotal + sum;

  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = tot;

}
```

```html
<div id="total" style="width:100px;padding:50px 0px; background-color:whitesmoke;text-align:center;">6 </div>

<!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<button id="5" value="5" onclick="showUser(this)">LIKE </button>

<button id="346" value="346" onclick="showUser(this)" style="background-color:rgb(116, 204, 49);">LIKE </button>

<button id="128" value="128" onclick="showUser(this)" style="background-color:rgb(116, 204, 49);">LIKE </button>

<button id="687" value="687" onclick="showUser(this)">LIKE </button>

<button id="183" value="183" onclick="showUser(this)" style="background-color:rgb(116, 204, 49);">LIKE </button>

<button id="555" value="555" onclick="showUser(this)">LIKE </button>
<!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
```

Comment: thanks thats excellent thinking. However, if like button 1 is clicked, the total increases by 1. if the same like button is clicked, the total must decrease. right now, if you click the same button twice, the value keeps adding and it doesnt reverse. Thanks

Comment: I don't really understand what's you're doing with the `likes` array.

Comment: I am using the like array to store multiple button ids. if we have buton 1, two and three, and button 1 two and three are clicked, then button 1 is clicked, the like array is used to decrease that specific button id from the total likes

Comment: I can make an illustration expllaining it if you'd still like to help ?

Answer (score 0):

First naive implementation can look like this

```js
class Counter {
  constructor(initial) {
    this.initial = initial
    this.white = [false, false, false]
    this.green = [false, false, false]
  }

  changeGreen(index) {
    this.green[index] = !this.green[index]
  }

  changeWhite(index) {
    this.white[index] = !this.white[index]
  }

  get total() {
    return this.initial + this.white.reduce((total, current) => total + current, 0) + this.green.reduce((total, current) => total - current, 0)
  }
}

let counter = new Counter(6)

const render = counter => {
  document.querySelector('#total').innerHTML = counter.total
}

render(counter)

;['#first', '#second', '#third'].map((selector, index) => {
  document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.target.classList.toggle('pressed')
    counter.changeWhite(index)
    render(counter)
  })
})

;['#fourth', '#fifth', '#sixth'].map((selector, index) => {
  document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.target.classList.toggle('pressed')
    counter.changeGreen(index)
    render(counter)
  })
})
```

```css
.green {
  background: #00aa00
}

.pressed {
  border-style: inset
}
```

```html
<div id="total">0</div>

<p>
  <button id="first">First</button>
  <button id="second">Second</button>
  <button id="third">Third</button>
  <button id="fourth" class="green">Fourth</button>
  <button id="fifth" class="green">Fifth</button>
  <button id="sixth" class="green">Sixth</button>
</p>
```

But after all I've finished with something like

```js
class Counter {
  constructor(initial, strategy) {
    this.initial = initial;
    this.elements = [];
    this.strategy = typeof strategy === 'function' ? strategy : () => {}
  }

  addElement(content, type, next) {
    const element = {
      content: content,
      type: type,
      state: false
    };
    this.elements.push(element);
    return next(element, this.elements.length - 1);
  }

  toggleElementState(index) {
    this.elements[index].state = !this.elements[index].state
  }

  get total() {
    return this.strategy(this.initial, this.elements)
  }
}

const initialize = () => {

  Counter.WHITE = Symbol('white');
  Counter.GREEN = Symbol('green');

  const counter = new Counter(6, (initial, buttons) => {
    return initial +
      buttons.filter(button => button.type === Counter.WHITE).reduce((total, current) => total + Number(current.state), 0) +
      buttons.filter(button => button.type === Counter.GREEN).reduce((total, current) => total - Number(current.state), 0)
  });

  const render = counter => {
    document.querySelector('#total').innerHTML = counter.total
  };

  const createButton = (element, index) => {
    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.setAttribute('data-id', index);
    button.classList.add(element.type === Counter.GREEN ? 'green' : 'none');
    button.textContent = element.content;
    document.querySelector('#buttons').appendChild(button)
  };

  const addButton = (type, ...selectors) => {
    selectors.forEach(selector => counter.addElement(selector, type, createButton));
  };

  render(counter);

  addButton(Counter.WHITE, '#first', '#second', '#third');
  addButton(Counter.GREEN, '#fourth', '#fifth', '#sixth');
  addButton(Counter.WHITE, '#first', '#second', '#third');

  document.querySelector('#buttons').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.target.classList.toggle('pressed');
    counter.toggleElementState(parseInt(e.target.dataset.id));
    render(counter)
  })

};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initialize);
```

```css
.green {
  background: #00aa00
}

.pressed {
  border-style: inset
}
```

```html
<div id="total">0</div>

<p id="buttons">
</p>
```